# setup reacuuring aws cloudwatch alarms

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

is there any elegant way to create a reacuuring alarms system to send sns notifications as long as the cloudwatch alarm is in ALARM status ?

i've searched the internet but most of the solutions are pretty complicated for a simple task

Answer (score 0):

You could create a simple process like this:

1. Create AWS Cloudwatch scheduled events: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-Scheduled-Rule.html
2. These scheduled events should trigger a Lambda
3. The Lambda function should check the alarm status. if the status is ALARM, trigger SNS to send a notification